# Delete Files in subfolders after encode

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I want to delete files in my subfolders with a PowerShell script.

I already tried using `Remove-Item` in PowerShell, but failed to set it up correctly...

This is the code I use for encoding:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | where BaseName -notlike '*`[HEVC]' | foreach {
ffmpeg -i $_ -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 "$($_.BaseName) [HEVC].mkv" -n
}
```

I want to either include `Remove-Item` [source file] in this script to delete the source files by checking the name of the file.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your pipeline output the file-info objects of those input files whose conversion via `ffmpeg` was successful (as implied by automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE` equaling `0`), and pipe them to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item):

The command below sends `ffmpeg`'s (stdout) output to the *display* only, via `Write-Host`, so as not to "pollute" the pipeline with its stdout output and only output the file-info objects; the alternative is to simply *suppress* `ffmpeg`'s output (error messages still print): `$null = ffmpeg ...`:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mkv | where BaseName -notlike '*`[HEVC]' | foreach {
  # Convert the input file and send ffmpeg's output to the display,
  # by piping to Write-Host, rather than trough the pipeline.
  ffmpeg -i $_ -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 "$($_.BaseName) [HEVC].mkv" -n |
    Write-Host
  # Conversion OK? Output the file-info object, which pipes it to Remove-Item.
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { $_ } 
} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note: Since [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) in PowerShell version 5 or above writes to the *information stream* (stream number `6`), which goes to the display by default, it is still possible to capture `ffmpeg`'s output from inside PowerShell, namely via [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `6>&1`; by contrast, a caller from outside PowerShell (such as a batch file) receives even `Write-Host` output directly via stdout.

---

In **PowerShell 7+** you can simplify the code inside the `foreach` loop via `&&`, the [pipeline-chain AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators) (its complementary OR (else) operator is `||`):

```
# (Details of the ffmpeg command omitted for brevity).
... | foreach {
  # The RHS of && is only executed if the command on the LHS succeeded, 
  # which in the case of external programs means: $LASTEXITCODE equals 0.
  ffmpeg $_ ... | Write-Host && $_
} | ...
```

Comment: if some fioles don't get deleted with this, would adding -f after Remove-Item do the trick?

Comment: @WorldTeacher: It _may_ help, but only if those files happen to have the read-only attribute set (and aren't also still in use by another process).

Comment: I tried using your provided script as a standalone, which worked fine, but when I started using it in my main script, which calls the script to start in a folder, I got an error stating that I don't have the necessary permissions. Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: @WorldTeacher: That sounds like a file-system permissions problem unrelated to PowerShell, so perhaps your script needs to run with elevation (as admin). If you need further assistance with this, please ask a _new_ question.